# select using join with 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Somebody help with this query, i would like to select just the company and the last login date

I've tried several joins, unsuccessfully
certainly using the wrong way, without logic

```
COMPANY TABLE
id|company|
1 | compA |
2 | compB |
3 | compC |
```

.

```
LOGIN TABLE
id|         data             |FKcompanyTable
1 | 2018-05-25 11:05:46      | 1  
2 | 2018-05-25 11:07:46      | 1  
3 | 2018-05-25 11:06:46      | 2  
4 | 2018-05-25 11:05:46      | 3  
5 | 2018-05-25 11:08:46      | 3
```

Comment: Which queries did you try already?

Comment: `select c.company, r.data from company inner join login on company.id = login.FKcompanyTable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is to use group by company_id and select max date as last login date

```
select 
COMPANY.id as "company_name",
max(LOGIN.data) as "last_login"
from
COMPANY
inner join LOGIN on(LOGIN.FKcompanyTable = COMPANY.id)
group by COMPANY.id
```

hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

```
Select company.id,company.company,tbl_lastdate.lastdate
from company left join (select id as companyid,max(data) as lastdate from Login group by FKcompanyTable)tbl_lastdate on company.id = tbl_lastdate.companyid
```

Comment: i did not undestand, what means tbl_lastdate.lastdate?

Comment: i changed my answer, tbl_lastdate is a virtual table what have the latest login time of companys and we call it tbl_lastdate and the field tbl_lastdate.lastdate is the field what contains the company last login time after we get lastlogin time of each company i a virtual table we join it with first table by company id , and there we go we have a query who show all companys and last login time for selecting one company its enough to add a where case

Comment: could you explain me `ON` at the ends, because i'm having `Syntax error: unexpected end of input`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Comment: I also thank you, but I have not been able to solve the problem yet and I will keep trying.

Comment: sory about that looks like my answer did not send correctly , i edited

Answer (score 0):

For your case, rather than using `JOIN`, I'd go with `SubQuery`.

```
SELECT
c.company AS 'company_name',
(SELECT data FROM LOGIN WHERE FKcompanyTable = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) as 'last_login'
FROM COMPANY c
```